# How do I use the HamburgerMenuIconItem and HamburgerMenuImageItem in my ObservableCollection<HamburgerMenuItem> created by Template Studio WPF

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, visual-studio-templates, windows-template-studio

I use Template Studio WPF to autogenerate the template of my UI.
In the "ShellViewModel" I set up the HamburgerMenuItem container

```
public ObservableCollection<HamburgerMenuItem> MenuItems { get; } = new ObservableCollection<HamburgerMenuItem>()
{
new HamburgerMenuGlyphItem() { Label = Resources.ShellMainPage, Glyph = "\uE8A5", TargetPageType = typeof(MainViewModel) },
new HamburgerMenuGlyphItem() { Label = Resources.ShellListDetailsPage, Glyph = "\uE8A5", TargetPageType = typeof(ListDetailsViewModel) },
};
```

Now I want to replace `HamburgerMenuGlyphItem` with `HamburgerMenuIconItem` or `HamburgerMenuImageItem`.

```
new HamburgerMenuIconItem() { Label = Resources.ShellListDetailsPage, Icon = Resources.ExcelParserIcoNeu, TargetPageType = typeof(ListDetailsViewModel) },
```

With `Resources.ExcelParserIcoNeu` I get an Object of Type `System.Drawing.Icon` defined in my Resources.

Here is the output of my `HamburgerMenuIconItem`

[image: what HamburgerMenuIconItem does]

As you can see, it does not render the Icon correctly.

Then I tried to use `HamburgerMenuImageItem` to do the job.

```
new HamburgerMenuImageItem(){ Label = Resources.ShellExcelParserPage, Thumbnail= new BitmapImage(new Uri(ExcelJpg)), TargetPageType = typeof(ExcelParserViewModel) }
```

with

```
static string ExcelJpg = "pack://application:,,,/Images/excelparsericoneu.jpg";
```

there I get the error message at runtime that path of the image can not be resolved. The Folder "Images" is part of my Project and contains the file as you can see in the following picture.

[image: Project tree]

If I pass the absolute path it works correctly.

I googled a lot regarding this topic but wars not able to find a solution.

Can you please help me with my issues or point me in the right direction?

thanks, alot.

Answer (score 0):

Now I figured out on part of my problem.
`HamburgerMenuImageItem` was not able to find the image at the specified location becaus I didn`t set the buildprocess setting of the image to ressource. Due to this the image was not  at "pack://application:,,,/Images/excelparsericoneu.jpg" and I got a runtime error.